# Can't connect virtual machine to host using virtual box

Tags: network-programming, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a host machine in Windows 7 that have a virtual box installed.

In virtual box I create a debian8 virtual machine and set a static Ip for it with the following configuration: IP: 192.168.56.101 Bcast: 192.168.56.255 Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.56.1 Network: 192.168.56.0

In the virtual machine I set the network as host only network to allow the host and virtual machine communication. The virtual box host-only network connection have the following configuration: IP: 192.168.56.1 Mask: 255.255.255.0

I think with this configurations the host and virtual machine should communicate. But I can't ping between them. When ping from one to another I always get:

Destination host unreachable.
I also have a web server in the debian8 virtual machine that is running but it also can't be used by the windows7 host machine.

There is something wrong with my networks configuration?

Comment: I resolve the problem bu change the IP address to 192.168.1.102. But this is not solution since I want to use the 192.168.1.101. I think the problem is  because I import the same machine to virtual box using the same IP, Maybe the 192.168.1.101 IP was reserved by virtual box some how.

Answer (score 0):

The IP of the debian machine is 192.168.56.101 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. That means that it can directly reach addresses in the range 192.168.56.0-192.168.56.255. The gateway is at 192.168.**52**.1, so it can't reach it.
Nevertheless, since both machines are in the same subnet, they should be able to communicate with each other without a gateway. Check for firewalls that might block pings on both machines.

Comment: Sorry @Malt the gateway 192.168.52.1 was a typo mistake. I already update the question using the correct gateway.